# sql server automated daily table partitioning

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to re design a table which holds daily logs and has hundreds of million rows. The concept is to keep data only for a one month period. The table will be partitioned per day, using a datetime field as the partition key. So for example for March i need to have 31 filegroups and 31 partitions. Once we get into April the process will have to insert into April 1st's partition and delete March 1st data and filegroup.

I am comfortable with the partition and filegroup creation, i am looking for suggestions on how to create the automated deletion process. Maybe an sql job which will drop the partition using `dateadd(m,-1,getdate())`? Is there something else i am missing?

Additional question: I will create year_month_day_partitions and the corresponding filegroups until 31-12-2020. Is there any way to create those automaticalluy or do we have to run the scripts manually when it is time?

Comment: Are you using a `RANGE RIGHT` partition function? Out of curiosity, why one filegroup per day? You could simplify the maintenance with a single filegroup.

Comment: yes i am using `range right` . My plan is to use separate filegroups, because the way i see it , maybe it will be  useful when dropping non needed partitions

Comment: you could also use trigger for your purpose but your idea about setting a job seems to be a better solution because you'll be able to always track the history an log of the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sliding window partition maintenance is usually done using a scheduled script or stored procedure (SQL Server Agent job or other scheduling system). Maintenance should be planned as to avoid costly data movement during `SPLIT` and `MERGE` because that requires about 4 times the logging as normal DML operations. To this end, make sure the partition that includes the boundary value is empty before `MERGE` and no rows are greater than the specified boundary when `SPLIT`. I suggest creating a few extra future partitions as a buffer to avoid data movement in case the maintenance isn't run as planned.

Below is an example daily sliding window maintenance script. This uses a similarly partitioned staging table for the purge since you are using SQL Server 2005 and partition-level `TRUNCATE` was introduced in SQL Server 2016. Note that SQL Server 2005 is out of support.

I see from your comment that you believe a separate filegroup/file per partition may be useful to drop partitions but that is not the case. This example uses a single filegroup for all partitions.

```
--example setup
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_Date (datetime) AS
    RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES();
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_LogTable AS
    PARTITION PF_Date ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);
DECLARE @PartitionBoundaryDate datetime = DATEADD(day, -31, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '', GETDATE()), ''));

WHILE @PartitionBoundaryDate < DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())
BEGIN
    ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PS_LogTable NEXT USED [PRIMARY];
    ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PF_Date() SPLIT RANGE(@PartitionBoundaryDate);
    SET @PartitionBoundaryDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @PartitionBoundaryDate)
END;
CREATE TABLE dbo.LogTable(DateColumn datetime INDEX cdx CLUSTERED) ON PS_LogTable(DateColumn);
CREATE TABLE dbo.LogTable_Staging(DateColumn datetime INDEX cdx CLUSTERED) ON PS_LogTable(DateColumn);
GO

--example partition maintenance scheduled nightly after midnight
BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    DECLARE @RetentionDays int = 31;
    DECLARE @FutureDays int = 7;
    DECLARE @OldestRetainedDate datetime = DATEADD(day, -@RetentionDays, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '', GETDATE()), ''));
    DECLARE @LatestRetainedDate datetime = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '', GETDATE()), '');
    DECLARE @LatestFutureBoundaryDate datetime = DATEADD(day, @FutureDays, @LatestRetainedDate);
    DECLARE @PartitionBoundaryDate datetime;
    DECLARE @Message nvarchar(2048);

    --make sure staging table is empty
    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.LogTable_Staging;

    BEGIN TRAN;
    --aquire exclusive table lock to avoid deadlocking during maintenance
    SELECT TOP(0) @PartitionBoundaryDate = DateColumn FROM dbo.LogTable WITH(TABLOCKX);

    --purge partition 1 in case data older than the first boundary was inserted
    SET @Message = 'Purging partition 1';
    PRINT @Message;
    ALTER TABLE dbo.LogTable SWITCH
        PARTITION 1 TO
        dbo.LogTable_Staging PARTITION 1;
    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.LogTable_Staging;

    --purge and remove expired partitions
    DECLARE @PartitionBoundaries TABLE(PartitionBoundaryDate datetime NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
    INSERT INTO @PartitionBoundaries(PartitionBoundaryDate)
        SELECT CAST(prv.value AS datetime)
        FROM sys.partition_functions AS pf
        JOIN sys.partition_range_values AS prv ON prv.function_id = pf.function_id
        WHERE
            pf.name = N'PF_Date'
            AND CAST(prv.value AS datetime) < @OldestRetainedDate;
    DECLARE ExpiredPartitionBoundaries CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT PartitionBoundaryDate
        FROM @PartitionBoundaries;

    OPEN ExpiredPartitionBoundaries;
    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM ExpiredPartitionBoundaries INTO @PartitionBoundaryDate;
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK;
        SET @Message = 'Purging data for ' + CONVERT(char(10), @PartitionBoundaryDate, 120);
        PRINT @Message;
        ALTER TABLE dbo.LogTable SWITCH
            PARTITION $PARTITION.PF_Date(@PartitionBoundaryDate) TO
            dbo.LogTable_Staging PARTITION $PARTITION.PF_Date(@PartitionBoundaryDate);
        TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.LogTable_Staging;
        ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PF_Date() MERGE RANGE(@PartitionBoundaryDate);
    END;
    CLOSE ExpiredPartitionBoundaries;
    DEALLOCATE ExpiredPartitionBoundaries;

    --create partitions for future days
    SET @PartitionBoundaryDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @LatestRetainedDate);
    WHILE @PartitionBoundaryDate < = @LatestFutureBoundaryDate
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
            FROM sys.partition_functions AS pf
            JOIN sys.partition_range_values AS prv ON prv.function_id = pf.function_id
            WHERE
                pf.name = N'PF_Date'
                AND CAST(prv.value AS datetime) = @PartitionBoundaryDate
        )
        BEGIN
            SET @Message = 'Creating partition for ' + CONVERT(char(10), @PartitionBoundaryDate, 120);
            PRINT @Message;
            ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PS_LogTable NEXT USED [PRIMARY];
            ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PF_Date() SPLIT RANGE(@PartitionBoundaryDate);
        END;
        SET @PartitionBoundaryDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @PartitionBoundaryDate);
    END;

    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;

    --better to use THROW in SQL 2012 and later
    DECLARE
         @ErrorNumber int
        ,@ErrorMessage nvarchar(2048)
        ,@ErrorSeverity int
        ,@ErrorState int
        ,@ErrorLine int;

    SELECT
        @ErrorNumber =ERROR_NUMBER()
        ,@ErrorMessage =ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ,@ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        ,@ErrorState =ERROR_STATE()
        ,@ErrorLine =ERROR_LINE();

    RAISERROR('Error %d caught at line %d: %s'
        ,@ErrorSeverity
        ,@ErrorState
        ,@ErrorNumber
        ,@ErrorLine
        ,@ErrorMessage);

END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: Hi Dan, can you possibly blog about automating sliding window (for Range Right) with latest (SS 2016+) features (truncate partition)? Allowing for different type of sliding (daily/weekly/monthly) by specifying a flag would be awesome.

Comment: @007, thanks for the suggestion. I'll add this to my blog TODO queue.

Comment: Hi, I'm also curious about the same what @007 wrote. Have You managed to blog about it?

Comment: @PiotrGrudzień, I forgot to follow up on this. Thanks for the reminder. Instead of a blog post, I'll create a public github repo with the code and post back here.

Comment: This is amazing, worked exactly as described. Thank you!!! One quick note - in order to add the scheduled maintenance as a SQL Agent cron job, I had to remove `BEGIN/END TRY`, `BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT`, and `GO` from the maintenance script (as apparently they're not supported as part of a jobstep).

Either way, wish I could upvote this by 1000. Exactly what I needed!