# MS SQL - Partitioning Tables for archiving data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've done some research now, but I haven't quite figured it out yet.

I have a table with about 2-3 years of data. That is currently 1.3TB.  The backup for this currently takes about 14 hours (is backed up to a NAS).
My idea was to partition the DB or table to it by date to possibly reduce backup time and also make queries more performant.
The server is currently running on SLQ 2016 and will be upgraded to 2019 this year.

My question about this (even if I partially know the answers, but I need confirmation on this):
Can I make the partitioning so that I have an "Active" part, where then a backup is created regularly? And old data is excluded? (does that make sense?)

Can I make the partitioning so that I always have the last 6 months as partition 1 and the rest is in partition 2? This would have to be changed daily. Is it possible to create the partition scheme accordingly?

Or would it be better to just push older data into an archive table?

Basically I'm just looking for best practice for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Table partitioning will not reduce database backup time unless you implement additional measures (read-only filegroups and partial backups). Partitioning will also not automagically improve performance but may reduce scan time in cases where partitions can be eliminated instead of a full table scan.

Table partitioning can facilitate efficient purging of old data using a sliding window strategy, such as a rolling 36 months. You will need to schedule a [sliding window script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55218323/sql-server-automated-daily-table-partitioning) for the regular partition maintenance since there is no declarative method with DDL.